# Are FICA payments deducted from Canadian citizens working in the US transferable to Canada when they return?

Tags: social-security

I am a Canadian citizen who worked in the US (on a TN visa) for 8 years before I returned to Canada. FICA payments were deducted from my salary. I did not meet the threshold. Are these payments transferable to the Canadian SS system?

Comment: By 'threshold' I assume you mean the 40 'quarters' (usually 10 years) of covered=taxed employment needed to qualify for US SS and/or Medicare benefits. Your US credits can't be _moved_ to the Canadian system but they can be _counted_ there for SS, see https://www.ssa.gov/international/Agreement_Pamphlets/canada.html#paid